# Solving Diophantine system of degree three that contains 4 equations with 16 unknowns over $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

The following Diophantine system

$25333-123\,a_{{2}}a_{{1}}-a_{{2}}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}-478\,a_{{2}}b_{{1}}-a_
{{2}}b_{{1}}c_{{3}}-223\,c_{{2}}a_{{1}}-c_{{2}}a_{{1}}b_{{3}}-589\,c_{
{2}}b_{{1}}-c_{{2}}b_{{1}}d_{{3}}-a_{{4}}=0
$
$
29151-123\,b_{{2}}a_{{1}}-b_{{2}}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}-478\,b_{{2}}b_{{1}}-b_
{{2}}b_{{1}}c_{{3}}-223\,d_{{2}}a_{{1}}-d_{{2}}a_{{1}}b_{{3}}-589\,d_{
{2}}b_{{1}}-d_{{2}}b_{{1}}d_{{3}}-b_{{4}}=0
$
$
54507-123\,a_{{2}}c_{{1}}-a_{{2}}c_{{1}}a_{{3}}-478\,a_{{2}}d_{{1}}-a_
{{2}}d_{{1}}c_{{3}}-223\,c_{{2}}c_{{1}}-c_{{2}}c_{{1}}b_{{3}}-589\,c_{
{2}}d_{{1}}-c_{{2}}d_{{1}}d_{{3}}-c_{{4}}=0
$
$
62645-123\,b_{{2}}c_{{1}}-b_{{2}}c_{{1}}a_{{3}}-478\,b_{{2}}d_{{1}}-b_
{{2}}d_{{1}}c_{{3}}-223\,d_{{2}}c_{{1}}-d_{{2}}c_{{1}}b_{{3}}-589\,d_{
{2}}d_{{1}}-d_{{2}}d_{{1}}d_{{3}}-d_{{4}}=0
$

has a solution

$
[a_{{1}}=1,b_{{1}}=2,c_{{1}}=3,d_{{1}}=4,a_{{2}}=5,b_{{2}}=7,c_{{2}}=
13,d_{{2}}=14,a_{{3}}=11,b_{{3}}=21,c_{{3}}=31,d_{{3}}=41,a_{{4}}=21,b
_{{4}}=31,c_{{4}}=41,d_{{4}}=51]
$

It is known that in 1900, David Hilbert proposed the solvability of all Diophantine equations as the tenth of his fundamental problems. In 1970, Yuri Matiyasevich solved it negatively, by proving that a general algorithm for solving all Diophantine equations cannot exist.

Is there any mathematical way to find the solution of the above system without doing loop over $\mathbb Z_n$?

How many solutions in  $\mathbb Z_n$?

Comment: You might consider formatting this to be legible: as it stands, I suspect most people won't take the trouble to try and figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the condition, $3(a+c)=2(b+d)$ and substituting as below in the given equations we have:

($a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$)=$(a,e,j,n)$

($b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$)=$(b,f,k,p)$

($c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$)=$(c,g,L,q)$

($d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4$)=$(d,h,m,r)$

$(s,t,u,v)=(25333,29151,54507,62645)$

$(x,y,z,w)=((L+478),(k+223),(j+123),(m+589))$

Because of common factor's the simultaneous equation given

by 'OP' simplifies to as shown below:

$2(s+t+u+v)=(a+c)[(e+f)(3x+2z)+(g+h)(2y+3w)]+2(n+p+q+r)$

But because the equation is cubic in nature & the number

of unknowns are sixteen which is more than number of equations

the problem is difficult. Unless the number of unknown's are reduced.

Comment: I have solved the problem. There many solutions. One can just simply solve the four equations for the unknowns a4, b4, c4, d4. Then the number of solutions is n^12.